# Move files directories and sub directories to another directory Conditionally (Move only Last 5 days created files and directories) in C#

Tags: c#

My Source directory "D:\Source"

Destination "D:\Destination"

source directory contains some files and folders with different creation dates,
i want to move all files and folders whose creation date less than last 5 days
for example today is **28/11/2015** and i want to Move all files and folders from source **before creating 23/11/205.**

i'm searching since 2 days but no success.

here is my Attempt

```
    var sourcePath = "D:\\Source";
    var destinationPath = "D:\\Destination";

    var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
    var files = (from filew in dInfo.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath)
                                     orderby filew.CreationTime.Date < DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-5) ascending
                                     select filew.Name).Distinct();

var directories = (from filew in dInfo.EnumerateDirectories(sourcePath)
                                 orderby filew.CreationTime.Date < DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-5) ascending
                                 select filew.Name).Distinct();
     foreach (var dir in directories)
     {
        var dest = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(dir));
                        Directory.Move(dir, dest);
     }

     foreach (var file in files)
     {
        var dest = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(file));
                            File.Move(file, dest);
     }
```

ERROR : Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.

please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO.  show us your attempts.  [faq]; [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: i've uploaded code in the question please check it.

Comment: Thank-you Muhammad Sohail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do it recursively as there can be sub directories within the directory, where the same rule would apply. Refer to code below.

```
public static void MoveFilesAndFolders(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
{
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath);

        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            var subDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

            //Create sub directory in the destination folder if the business rules is satisfied
            if (DateTime.Today.Subtract(File.GetCreationTime(directory)).Days < 5)
            {
                var newDestinationDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(destinationPath, subDirectory.Name));
                MoveFilesAndFolders(subDirectory.FullName, newDestinationDirectory.FullName);
            }
        }

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

            //Copy the file to destination folder if the business rule is satisfied
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                var newFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileName);
                if (!File.Exists(newFilePath) && (DateTime.Today.Subtract(File.GetCreationTime(file)).Days < 5)))
                {
                    File.Move(file, newFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories` without parameters:

```
dInfo.EnumerateFiles()
dInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
```

The information about `sourcePath` is already in the `dInfo` object. The parameter would be used to apply a filter.

UPDATE:

And the `EnumerateFiles()` function just returns the file names without pathes. So you should use something like that:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var src = Path.Combine(sourcePath, file);
    var dest = Path.Combine(destinationPath, file);
    File.Move(src, dest);
}
```

Comment: Additional info to OP - Other methods of DirectoryInfo which accept path would raise the same exception if you include drive letter in the path parameter. DI object already knows about the root drive when you instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Now sir it gives me an exception on File.Move(file,dest)    

Exception:

Could not find file 'D:\Hamza\FTPWindowsService\FtpUpload\FtpUpload\bin\Debug\s1.txt'.
this is not my destination path i don't know why it gives me this exception

Comment: i've changed accordingly but exception is still there. it's targeting my projects Debug Directory.. :(

Comment: Is it the same kind of exception?

Comment: Did you apply the change accordingly in the directory loop? My change was just for the file loop.

Comment: yes i've changed in both loops it gives exception in both loops

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint on `File.Move` and check each variable: src, dest, sourcePath, destinationPath and file. You should see there in any way, why your input parameter to `File.Move` is wrong. And you should find out how this wrong value is produced.